# Unity: Spawning enemies on a procedurally generated map

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, spawn

So I've been Googling this for a while, but I don't really know what to look for, so I'm gonna ask all of you nice people for help instead.

I'm working on a procedural level creator for my first game. Part of the code is inspired by the tutorial here, but I try to do as much as I can on my own. Anyways, here's the code I need help with, which is probably ugly as all hell, and I'll explain what I need help with after:

```
Vector3 RandomPosition ()
{
    int randomIndex = Random.Range (0, gridPositions.Count);

    Vector3 randomPosition = gridPositions [randomIndex];

    gridPositions.RemoveAt (randomIndex);

    return randomPosition;
}


void LayoutObjectAtRandom (GameObject[] tileArray, int minimum, int maximum)
{
    int objectCount = Random.Range (minimum, maximum);

    for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; i++)
    {
        Vector3 randomPosition = RandomPosition ();

        GameObject tileChoice = tileArray [Random.Range (0, tileArray.Length)];

        Instantiate (tileChoice, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

void spawnTomcats () // Figure out a way to use the RandomPosition to exclude used tiles in enemySpawn
{
    int enemyCount = (int)Mathf.Log (level, 2f);

    for (int i = 0; i < enemyCount; i++)
    {
        Vector3 enemySpawn = new Vector3 (columns + (Random.Range (0, 5)), rows - (Random.Range (7, 14)), 0f);

        GameObject tileChoice = enemyTiles [Random.Range (0, enemyTiles.Length)];

        Instantiate (tileChoice, enemySpawn, Quaternion.identity);
    }

public void SceneSetup (int level)
{
    BoardSetup ();
    InitialiseList ();
    spawnTomcats ();

    LayoutObjectAtRandom (impassableObjects, impassableCount.minimum, impassableCount.maximum);

    Instantiate (heatCat, new Vector3 (columns - 8, rows - (Random.Range(7, 14)), 0f), Quaternion.identity);
}
}
```

So, what I need is for "Vector3 enemySpawn" to choose a tile within the specified parameters, but that aren't already used by the instantiating of impassableObjects in the SceneSetup function. Everything works on the spawning part, but my "Tomcats" sometimes spawn on top of impassableObjects. I've tried integrating the RandomPosition() method several ways, but haven't really succeeded.

If you need any more information, like my variables, let me know! I'm not really sure how much is needed as I'm still a beginner.

Every piece of advice will be greatly appreciated.

Joel Crosby.

Comment: If my answer helps please don't forget to mark it as accepted, if not, let me know and I'll elaborate

Comment: I have not and will not forget. Just want to get it working properly so I can post my solution at the same time. Your post gave me just enough perspective to be able to work it out by myself, so I thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to maintain a `List<Vector3> ImpassibleObjects` and check against that prior to instantiating a new tomcat. Probably including a bit of a space around it too.

Something along the lines of:

```
foreach (Vector3 impLoc in ImpassibleObjects)
{
    if (randomPosition - impLoc < threshold)
    {
          CalculateNewRandomPositionAndRecheck();
    }
}
```

Should work, good luck!

Comment: Spent a day trying to get it right, but I can't really seem to get it. I tried making a List<Vector3> objectPositions, and then do objectPositions.Add (randomPosition) right above gridPosition.RemoveAt() in the RandomPosition() method, but I don't get how to measure objectPositions up against enemySpawn. No matter what I do it just ends up not spawning anything. 

I'm a scrub, I know.

Comment: To get the distance between two `Vector3`s you simply take the absolute value of one subtracted from the other. Your `threshold` should be determined by you and should be a bit bigger than the radius of a circle that contains your impassible object. It's then a simple matter of checking your new spawning location isn't within the threshold of any items in your list. It might help me work out what's going wrong if you attach your new code.